# Was Swastika a universally-recognized symbol of fascism as early as 1925?

Tags: nazism, fascism, symbols

In the Soviet sci-fi film "Napoleon Gas" of 1925, there is a secret society, called "Fascist Order Black Klan" in the United States. The order's uniform seems to be similar to that of the Ku Klux Klan except they wear clothing of black color instead of white, and with a huge [swastika on it](https://youtu.be/VY19iHnez4w?t=985). The order's aim is to destroy the USSR, it has as its (secret) member the US war minister, who illegally produces chemical weapons in a plant, disguising it as an aniline paint and is a member of the "International Fascist League".

It seems from the film, the swastika symbol is closely associated with fascism, including the international one. Is this feature of the film anachronistic and a fantasy of the authors, or does it reflect the realities of 1925?

**UPDATE**
This question is not about swastika being an anti-semitic symbol, but about its association with fascism specifically. As I know, fascist Italy did not use swastika as its symbol and Hitler's party was far from coming to power, so what made the authors use the swastika as an emblem of an American fascist society (that assembled an air unit to bomb Leningrad with illegally produced chemical weapons later in the film)?

Comment: What research have you done?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the swastika in The Great Gatsby anti-semitic?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/27382/is-the-swastika-in-the-great-gatsby-anti-semitic)

Comment: @PieterGeerkens of course, not, because this question is not about swastka being anti-semitic, but about its association with fascism (as I know, fascist Italy did not use swastika as its symbol and Hitler's party was far from coming to power)

Comment: Read the answer. That the question is not identical doesn't prevent the answer from being identical.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens well in your answer you say it was not even associated with Nazi Party at the time. If so, I wonder what made the creators of the film to use swaskika as a symbol of an American fascist society. It even decorates the walls in the palace where they gather.

Comment: Please update the question to indicate why the other answers are not responsive.  Also update with the research you've done on the symbology of the any American fascist societies.

Comment: The swastika's shown in the film (on the black garments) are of the [Fylfot (left-facing) and Gammadion (right-facing) types, with the broken portions of its legs shortened](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swastika#Appearance) and **not** the Nazi swastika used a 5 × 5 diagonal grid, but with the legs unshortened.

Comment: The film also shows the **lower rank** members wearing the Gammadion (right-facing) and the **higher rank** members the Fylfot (left-facing) form. (The lower ranks are bowing to the higher ranks).

Comment: There would seem to be a problem with citing a Soviet film as an example of universalism.  After all, the USSR was a fairly closed society, so how would the film's makers have access to accurate information?

Comment: @jamesqf i dont think the ussr was closed in 1925

Answer (score 6):

As pointed out by user LangLangC, both the question and the answers should really be from the point of view of educated and/or politically interested parts of Soviet society. Unfortunately I do not speak any Russian, so I can only answer this for educated and/or politically interested parts of *German* society.

However, the Soviet Union did often take notice of events in Europe (see e.g. stuff named after Rosa Luxemburg and Karl Liebknecht, two communist leaders murdered in 1919, by members of the same political movement that would bear swastikas on their helmets in 1920), so what was recognized in Germany *may* also have been recognized in the Soviet Union.

---

The German political intellectual [Kurt Tucholsky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurt_Tucholsky) wrote several poems with allusions to Swastikas in the [early](https://www.textlog.de/tucholsky-rathenau.html) and [mid](http://www.zeno.org/Literatur/M/Tucholsky,+Kurt/Werke/1925/Farbenklavier)-1920s (the German term is "Hakenkreuz"). So my understanding is that this was commonly recognized as a symbol of right-wing extremism *within Germany* by the mid-1920s if not slightly earlier.

This seems to stem from the [Marinebrigade Ehrhardt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marinebrigade_Ehrhardt), which was quite prominent in the destruction of the Munich Soviet Republic and during the Kapp-Putsch, and which extensively used swastika markings during the latter.

Given that the Soviet Union was fairly interested in what happened in Germany, it is possible that the film's inspiration for that symbolism is from there. On the other hand, as the [answers to the question linked by Pieter Geerkens](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/27382/is-the-swastika-in-the-great-gatsby-anti-semitic) point out, there is also a connection between swastikas and White Russians during the Russian Civil War, which may be closer to home.

---

P.S. Another data point re. symbolism of the Hakenkreuz *in Germany* (and the knowledge thereof) may be obtained by searching through the Weltbühne editions archived at archive.org. Weltbühne was a leftist political magazine in the 1920s and 1930s. Editions before 1920 on archive.org are not easily searchable due to OCR problems, but the word appears only once in the first edition of 1920 (in reference to the Kapp-Putsch) and about five to 20 times in subsequent editions. So my guess is it got well-known *in Germany* during and after the Kapp-Putsch.

Comment: But that brigade did not use swastika, did they?...

Comment: @Anixx: One of the two pictures in the wikipedia article has a lorry full of Brigade members with swastikas on their helmets. Direct link: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Bundesarchiv_Bild_146-1971-091-20,_Kapp-Putsch,_Marine-Brigade_Erhardt.jpg

Comment: Two more pictures from the Kapp-Putsch with swastikas: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Bundesarchiv_Bild_146-1972-033-17,_Kapp-Putsch,_Panzerfahrzeug,_Berlin.jpg and https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Bundesarchiv_Bild_183-R16976,_Kapp-Putsch,_Berlin.jpg

Comment: Thanks, I see now!

Comment: May I place a little ad? Related: https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/47652

Comment: See [Symbols of state independence (German version only)](https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swastika#Symbol_staatlicher_Unabh%C3%A4ngigkeit), where the versions shown in the film were used in eastern Europe (Finnland, Poland, Russia) shortly after WWI to 1929.

Comment: "Within Germany" is surely not the only angle to analyse. Q asks for "internationally", when in reality it should mainly ask for "within the SU", as that would be the primary market for the movie! For SU and international communist agitation, I'd like to see some quotes that limit the scope or corroborate the movie. For 'internationally' look at papers like https://books.google.com/books?id=DsRYAAAAMAAJ&q=swastika+fascist from 1922. "Commonly" is also a strange category for an avantgarde agitation sci-fi movie.

Comment: @LangLangC Agree. Unfortunatly my Russian is limited to Красный Октябрь and Ротфронт (the names of two sweets producers that I am aware of) . This makes a bit hard for me to look at it from the Soviet angle. Thus "it is possible"

Comment: @Jan Rotfront is German, not Russian (language)

Comment: @Anixx It is also a Moscow based Confectionery factory, founded in 1826 and renamed in 1931 as a sign of solidarity with the [Roter Frontkämpferbund](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roter_Frontk%C3%A4mpferbund) after a visit by Ernest Thälmann. [Рот Фронт (фабрика)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%BE%D1%82_%D0%A4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82_(%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0))

Answer (score 2):

No, the Swastika was not generally (especially not world wide) taken as the symbol of Fascism in 1925. The Soviet film (Наполеон Газ 1925 / Napoleon Gas) does **not** use the Nazi-Swastika, it uses the Fylfot (left-facing) and Gammadion (right-facing) swastikas forms (see images below).

Adolf Hitler and his party were generally unknown at the time outside of Bavaria. When the party was founded in January 1920, the later Nazi-Swastika was allready in use by right-wing groups. Most notably by the **Marine-Brigade Ehrhardt** during the [Kapp-Putsch](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kapp-Putsch) of March 1920.
The party itself had just been refounded in February 1925 and the first band of **Mein Kampf** was published in July 1925 (the second in December 1926).

> [Nationalsozialistische Deutsche Arbeiterpartei](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nationalsozialistische_Deutsche_Arbeiterpartei)
> Im Deutschen Reich war die NSDAP **bis zu den Reichstagswahlen 1928** *nur eine von mehreren antisemitischen und völkischen Parteien*, zeigte aber spätestens bei der Reichstagswahl ihre herausragende Stellung in diesem Spektrum.
>
> > In the German Reich, the NSDAP was *only one of several anti-Semitic and ethnic parties* **until the Reichstag elections in 1928**, but showed its prominent position in this spectrum at the latest by the Reichstag elections.

The [Deutschvölkische Freiheitspartei (DVFP)](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutschv%C3%B6lkische_Freiheitspartei) did use the symbol in the 1924 Reichstag election:

[image] ([img src](https://www.dhm.de/lemo/bestand/objekt/wahlplakat-der-dvfp-1924.html))

which had split from the main Nationalistic party [Deutschnationale Volkspartei (DNVP)](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutschnationale_Volkspartei) in 1922.

The **DNVP** recieved in the 1924 election 19,5%, the **DVFP** 6,6%.

---

If any symbol generally represented Fascism at that time, then that of the [National Fascist Party](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Fascist_Party) of Italy (**Classical Fascism**) that had been ruling since 1922.

[image]

**A Bundle of sticks and Axe**

---

- [Наполеон Газ 1925 / Napoleon Gas](https://youtu.be/VY19iHnez4w?t=1052)

The swastika's shown in the film (on the black garments) are of the [Fylfot (left-facing) and Gammadion (right-facing) types, with the broken portions of its legs shortened](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swastika#Appearance) and not the Nazi swastika used a 5 × 5 diagonal grid, but with the legs unshortened.

[image: 17:32, 1052]

- [16:42] 2 **higher** rank members being lead to dressing room

  - being escorted by 2 **lower** ranked (subservient) members

[image: 17:04, 1024]

- [17:04] **higher** ranked member being let into secret chamber after dressing (left)

  - **lower** ranked member guarding/opening the secret door (right)
    [image]

[image: 17:32, 1052]

- [17:32] **higher** ranked member being seated inside meeting chamber

---

See also [Symbols of state independence (German version only)](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swastika#Symbol_staatlicher_Unabh%C3%A4ngigkeit) and [Western use of the swastika in the early 20th century](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_use_of_the_swastika_in_the_early_20th_century)
, where the versions shown in the film were used in eastern Europe (Finnland, Poland, Russia) shortly after WWI to 1929.

> Since the early Middle Ages the sign of the swastika was well established among all Slavic lands. Known as swarzyca, <strike>it was primarily associated with one of the Slavic gods named Svarog</strike>.

**Note**': Doubts have been expressed about the reliability of original source used by Wikipedia for this quote.

[image]

- Badges worn by the Kalmyk formations of the Red Army in 1919

  - Gammadion (right-facing), with the broken portions of its legs

[image]

- Federacja Polskich Związków Obrońców Ojczyzny, 1929

  - Gammadion (right-facing), with the broken portions of its legs

> [Western use of the swastika in the early 20th century](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_use_of_the_swastika_in_the_early_20th_century)
> The Nazi Party adopted the symbol in the 1920s, and [its use in Western countries faded after the Nazi association became dominant in the 1930s.](https://www.bbc.com/news/magazine-29644591) In recent decades many public swastikas have been removed or covered over, although others have been deliberately retained as part of debate about historical preservation.

[image]

[image]

- 1916 White swastika 6 pence war savings coupon. Jones Type 1, Issue 1 (United Kingdom)

---

**Sources**:

- [Swastika - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swastika#Appearance)

  - [Fylfot, Gammadion - Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fylfot)
  - [Swastika, Symbols of state independence (German version only)](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swastika#Symbol_staatlicher_Unabh%C3%A4ngigkeit)
- [Kapp-Putsch](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kapp-Putsch)

  - [Deutschnationale Volkspartei (DNVP)](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutschnationale_Volkspartei)
  - [Deutschvölkische Freiheitspartei (DVFP)](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutschv%C3%B6lkische_Freiheitspartei)
- [Nationalsozialistische Deutsche Arbeiterpartei](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nationalsozialistische_Deutsche_Arbeiterpartei)
- [Western use of the swastika in the early 20th century](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_use_of_the_swastika_in_the_early_20th_century)

  - [How the world loved the swastika - until Hitler stole it - BBC News](https://www.bbc.com/news/magazine-29644591)

Comment: I think you are missing the bigger picture to some extent. "Fascism" has always been used as a shorthand for rightwing extremism. Especially in the soviet sphere. The swastika had been used by German right-wingers since before WWI and very publicly so when they tried to overthrow the German government in 1920. So "NSDAP was generally unknown" (even if it was true, which it is not) does not imply that the swastika was generally not recognized as a symbol of rightwing extremism.

Comment: Front page of a Berlin newspaper from November 10th, 1923, mentioning Hitler right below WWI second-in-command Ludendorff: http://zefys.staatsbibliothek-berlin.de/index.php?id=dfg-viewer&set%5Bmets%5D=http%3A%2F%2Fcontent.staatsbibliothek-berlin.de%2Fzefys%2FSNP27112366-19231110-0-0-0-0.xml

Comment: @Jan But in other countries (and even inside Germany in 1925) rightwing extremist parties didn't use the Swastika as their symbol. The DNVP (which won 19.5% in the 1924 election) didn't do so. Their ratical split off (DVFP, 6.6%) did. This lumping togeather of different fractions is misleading. The OP question is about **how was seen in 1925**, *not how it was perceived after 1945*.

Comment: @Jan The true expansion of the NSDAP in northern Germany (eventually replacing the DVFP) started in 1925/26. In the Reichstag election of 1928 they recieved 2.6% (DVPN 14.3%, DVFP 0%). The newspaper report of 1923 only shows that the name was not completely unknown. They became truly relevant during the 1929-30 period when they overhauled the DVPN (7%) with 18.3% in the 1930 election.

Comment: A fundamental problem apparent here is that DVFP used this as own self branding when operating as ersatz for NS party in cooperation with its members, while mother party DNVP and NSDAP all had *affinity* to the symbol and for what it stood (=much more%). As this is a Soviet film: we need more a look at 'branding the enemy'? As such it seems that a look at KKK (what's their symbol?) ***+*** Swastika, American (=world capitalism, general reactionary forces, how did they get to Leningrad on land?) might be helpful? Or: why the hoods if the cross would suffice? How did Soviets label 'enemies'?

Comment: @LаngLаngС The usage of the Fylfot and Gammadion form in the film seems to be clear: *Since the early Middle Ages the sign of the swastika was well established among all Slavic lands. Known as swarzyca, it was primarily associated with one of the Slavic gods named Svarog.* and thus would be familiar to the audience.

Comment: @LаngLаngС Why both were used can only be speculated. My speculation would be: Possibly to give the audience the impression that even in the US upperclasses a 'Master/Slave' relation existed. Such bows, between whites, in the US is however unrealistic. But for the Soviet viewer plausible.

Comment: Unsure. From *your* answer (Latvian airforce ugunstkrust!) it seems nationalist, reactionary undertones dominate that image. Nation separating from Russia/USSR, white suprematists, völkisch 'thinkers' faceless secretive plotting hierarchies based on backwardish concepts (Slavic gods, Christian cross, all quit un-Marxian) based on destructive conquest vs universalist, world revolution (of course: Soviet peaceful), flat hierarchy/more equality, constructive & inventive Red Utopia; which as a successful example threatens all the oldish powers embodied in (only half-envisioned) "fascists"?

Comment: @LаngLаngС For a symbol that has be around for over 11.000 years, in all parts of the world (often at the same time), there *should* be no surprise that each area could have used in a different mannor. Thats why **lumping** these things togeather, leads to false conclusions. Stating that because later, in the 1930's, it became a Nazi symbol, 'those that bought the 6 pence war savings coupon in 1916 were nazi sympathsiizers' **or** 'those that had the 'Drink Coca-Cola in bottles' Keyring in the early 1920's were secret gestapo agents' : is nonsence.

Comment: @LаngLаngС The likelihood is high that those who participated in the Kapp-Putsch on the 13th of March 1920 didn't even know who Adolf Hitler was or that 3 weeks before the DAP had been renamed to DSDAP and that the Swastika they were using would also be used for that party. So a lot of assumptions are being made based on facts that came to be kbown in the future.

Comment: Svarog has nothing to do with swastika. You are using either neo-nazi or neo-pagan sources

Comment: @Anixx The quote is from the Wikipedia artical: [Western use of the swastika in the early 20th century, Poland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_use_of_the_swastika_in_the_early_20th_century#Poland). Should any correction be needed, it should be done there.

Comment: @MarkJohnson yes, they link a Neo-Nazi pseudoscientific neopaganist blog as a source: https://blog.slowianskibestiariusz.pl/en/symbols/svarga-kolovrat/

Comment: @Anixx Then you should report that to Wikipedia (my polish is not good enough to determine this). If they remove it there, I will remove it here. I will now add a warning about the reliability the source used by Wikipedia. Has been added under quote, with the last portion struck out.